# Showing that there is a bijection between real numbers and Dedekind cuts?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So the question I was solving asked the following:

A set such as A(defined below) can be defined to be a Dedekind cut if the following holds.
A= {$ x \in Q: x < y$}. Also $sup(A)$ not in  $A$. Show that there is a bijection from real numbers to Dedekind cuts. I do not know how to do this because according to me each point on the number line is in a one-to-one correspondence with the set of real numbers, and there are an infinite number of them. So I am not sure how I can prove that there is a bijection between $R$ and the set of Dedekind cuts.

Comment: What set is $y$ an element of?

Comment: That is not the definition of a Dedekind cut. $A$ is a Dedekind cut if $\{x\in\Bbb Q:x<y\}\subseteq A$ whenever $y\in A$, and $\sup A\notin A$.

Comment: "Show that there is a bijection from real numbers to Dedekind cuts." In my book, the real numbers _are_ the Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott With the added caveats that $A\neq\Bbb Q, \varnothing$, of course.

Comment: @Arthur: Depends on whether you want the completion or the compactification. But yes, here it’s pretty clear that the completion is wanted.

Comment: Unless you specify **precisely** which properties of real numbers you are assuming, your question **cannot** be answered validly. Please specify.

Comment: Dedekind cut is used to define real number. Your question mean, that you have some other definition of real number, or it have not sense. Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Denote $Q_y=\{q\in\mathbb{Q}: q<y\}$, and consider $Q_y\subset\mathbb{R}$.

**Step 1:** In $\mathbb{R}$, $\sup(Q_y)=y$.

Proof: By lub property, let $u=\sup(Q_y)$. If $y\neq u$, by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $u<q<y$. Hence $q\in Q_y$. But $u\ge q$, since $u=\sup(Q_y)$, contradiction with $u<q$! Hence $y=u$.

**Step 2:** Denote $A$ to be D. cut. For every D. cut $A$, there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $A=Q_y$.

Since $A$ is bounded above, let $y=\sup(A)$. Let $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $q<y$. Choose $\varepsilon=y-q$ and by approximation, $\exists x\in A$ s.t. $x>q=y-\varepsilon$. Since $A$ does not contain $y$, there are no rationals $\ge y$ that is in $A$. So $A$ consists of rationals $<y$, which is definition of $Q_y$.

**Step 3:** There exists a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

It suffices to show that $\sup(A)$ is a bjection between $A$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

**One-to-one:** Let $A$ and $B$ be distinct D. cuts of $\mathbb{Q}$. WLOG, let $q$ be rational s.t. $q\in A$, but $q\notin B$. No rationals $\ge q$ is in $B$, by definition of D. cut. Hence all numbers in $B$ are smaller than $q$, hence $q$ is upper bound for $B$. Hence $\sup(B)\leq q$. But since $q\in A$, there exists a number $\ge q$ in $A$. Since $A$ is D. cut, and does not contain its supremum, hence $q$ is not upper bound for $A$, and $\sup(A)>q$. Hence different D. cuts have different suprema.

**Onto:** Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$, $Q_y$ is a D. cut by **step 2**, and $\sup(Q_y)=y$ by **step 1**.

Hope this answers your questions, and I use different notations from yours.

Comment: Why does it suffice to show that sup(A) is the bijection? And what do you mean that that the sup(A) IS the bijection requested.

Comment: @user00000000001899 Each D. cut has a supremum, so it is a function from cuts to real numbers.